# Getting info on users and businesses

Tags: linkedin-api

I am simply looking to get the number of followers a business has and the number of connections a user has, given a link to the business or user's page.

Can this be done? I don't see any docs describing the api usage. From everything I have seen, I can only get info for my own account which isn't exactly useful to me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the number of followers of a company if you are not one of the admin. You will get a response that looks like that

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Member does not have permission to get company.",
  "requestId": "ACFFOSM3QJ",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1483027565311
}
```

You will also get an error if you try to get information of a member ...

This API is not made for it so I used a workaround with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/). As it is described on the main page, CasperJS "*allows you to build full navigation scenarios*". So I have simulated user interaction to programmatically connect to LinkedIn and retrieve number of followers and number of connections on pages.

It works but it is extremly dependant of page structure, so you must avoid this solution if it is for a long term application.